# How to notifyDataSetChanged to all recyclerview sections

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, sectionedrecyclerviewadapter

I'm using section luizgrp sectionedrecyclerviewadapter with sections and headers ,
and on item select i change the text color then notifyData but it reflects only in one section , every section has a selected item colored , how can i notify the whole list?

```
 @Override
public void onBindItemViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final ItemViewHolder itemHolder = (ItemViewHolder) holder;
    if(position == selectedPosition) {
        itemHolder.txtTime.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00aaff"));
        itemHolder.txtType.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00aaff"));
    } else {
        itemHolder.txtTime.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000")); 
        itemHolder.txtType.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    }


        itemHolder.rootView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectedPosition=position;
                recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: add only  notifyDataSetChanged() instead of recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: can you show me your activity code also where you are setting adapter?

Comment: try it by setting the color in `onCreateViewHolder()` so that each time when your row is created it will set the color

Comment: @Anonymous can't resolve notifyDataSetChanged() only

Comment: what?your extending recycler adapter only no?post your whole code,if it is adapter then thtat method should be onBindViewHolder but yours it is onBindItemViewHolder

Comment: i'm using https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter 
so the code is written in class MySection extends StatelessSection
not adapter

Comment: If the user clicks on item #1 of section #1, do you want to ONLY change the color of item #1 of section #1 or you want to change the color of ALL items #1 of all sections?

Comment: In the onClick event you are storing the position of item #1 in section #1, not in the whole adapter, if you want the color to be changed only in one section you should use the value from [holder.getAdapterPosition()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getAdapterPosition()) to store in selectedPosition

Comment: and use the value from [getPositionInSection](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter/blob/918337f66321055c7621377e5f5254b9b8078e4c/library/src/main/java/io/github/luizgrp/sectionedrecyclerviewadapter/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.java#L376) when comparing with position

Comment: Hi @Amira Rabie i would like to ask how did you solved this? I got the same issue.. Thankyou :)